# Holonomic Constraints

Tags: motion-planning, linear-algebra

I'm currently reading the book "Principles of Robot Motion" by Choset and came across the following statement in Chapter 3 on Configuration Spaces, in a section where they discuss the dimensions of a configuration space (Section 3.3, pg 48, for anyone who has the book):

> Each linearly independent holonomic constraint on a system reduces the dimension of the system's configuration space by one.

I'm having a little trouble understanding what makes a constraint *linearly independent*. Independent with reference to what?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Holonomic constraints are a difficult topic to grasp at the beginning. A nice answer I found is given here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409951/what-are-holonomic-and-non-holonomic-constraints . From the linked answer one can see that a holonomic constraint reduces a system's degrees of freedom by one.

Now imagine that you have a system and you can formulate different holonomic constraints the form of equations (see linked answer). Note that there can be different ways to formulate those constraints, e.g. different variables depending on how you define it. However, those equations will still describe the same constraint. Sometimes this is not as obvious as it seems and one has to do the math. By looking at the math we can see if two holonomic constraint equations are describing the same thing by checking if the constraint equations are linearly independent or not. If they are, we can say that they describe the same constraint, just in different ways. And since they describe just the same constraint they will not reduce the systems degrees of freedom by one individually, but together. In contrary if they are linearly independent, they are indeed describing two different constraints and therefore will reduce the systems degrees of freedom individually by one. Note that I explained it in terms of degrees of freedom of the system, but this is equivalent for the dimension of the configuration space.